# get the html of the second td of selected tr of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a datatable...

Now i have this code, which chages the class or a tr to "selected" when clicked..

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#domains_list tbody").on( "click", "tr", function () 
        {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        } );

});
```

Now my datatable comes like this...

[image]

[image]

Now as you can see there are two pages showing different selected rows

now i write this code

```
$('#butto').click(function()
{
$("#domains_list").find("tr.selected").each(function() 
    {
        $(this).find("td:eq(1)").each(function()
            {
                alert($(this).html());
            });
    });
});
```

this above code was intended to show all the `htm`l in the second `<td>` of the selected `<tr>`

But the problem is, it alerts only the `<td>` html of `<tr>` in the `opened page`...

i.e. `if page 1 is open then it alerts only <td> html of page 1,`

```
if page 2 is open then it alerts only <td> html of page 2,
```

How can i make it to alert all the html of the  irrespective of the page opened?

Comment: http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

Answer (score 0):

For "second td", Use `nth-of-type`:

```
$(this).find("td:nth-of-type(2)").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

You might be able to use it like this ...

```
$("#domains_list").find("tr.selected td:nth-of-type(2)").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

The :nth-of-type(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Tip: Look at the :nth-child() selector to select the element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example page, I was able to log all the the names inside the first TD of each selected rows using the following code:

```
$("tr.selected").each(function(){
console.log($(this).find("td:first").html());
});
```

if you need a TD other than the first one, you can use the `:nth-child(index)` selector instead of `:first`

check the following image, and do let me know if this is not what you want.

[image]